# What about the types int2, int3, float2, float3 etc

Tags: c++

I've seen different code snippets using these types, but I haven't seen if they are defined in some <standard header file> or just defined in a "local header file" or even at file level.

So what Im wondering is: Is there any standard header file that defines these types? Or is there some standard definitions that everyone uses that I should copy?

I guess that a possible and common use to these types are representing coordinates, am I wrong?

Is there anything else I should think about if I want to use these to represent positions in a grid? Any reasons why or why not to use them?

EDIT:

Clarification: int2 means a pair of ints, float3 means a triplet of floats.

If these types were predefined somewhere it would be nice to use them instead of having to write it from scratch including the standard algebraic functions (operator+, operator-, etc.).

Comment: types are only names, don't fuss too much about them. If you need to pass around lots of 2D points, why not just use a `struct Point2D { int x; int y; };`. This is probably exactly what these types are. Have you tracked down their definition in the project you mention in your post?

Comment: I have just found snippets of source code on the web so i haven't been to dig deeper in the projects for any definitions. But I got a tip about CUDA so I'll look into it! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These types aren't a part of standard C++. They might either be defined in some third-party library, or you're looking at some other dialect or language.

GPU code (Shader languages such as GLSL, Cg or HLSL, or GPGPU stuff like CUDA or OpenCL) typically defines types like these though, as names for the corresponding SIMD datatypes.

Comment: Those SIMD datatypes, is it anything anyone uses?

Comment: In those languages, they're extremely commonly used, yes, because the GPU is designed to work with such types. In regular C++, those specific types don't exist, but on many CPUs other SIMD types are available instead (x86 has __m128, for example, which is basically 4 floats), and those are sometimes used, but not as often, and typically only in performance-sensitive code.

Comment: Soo, anyone care to tell me why this was downvoted? Did I say anything incorrect?

Answer (score 10):

They are used in CUDA (and openCL?) where you have specific sized floats and memory usage and alignment is a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no standard header file that defines these types.
According to your description `int2` means a pair of two `int`s which can be represented in C++ as `std::pair<int, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

These types are not standard and I've never seen them.  Are you sure they weren't used as (terrible choices of) identifiers instead of types?

Some non-standard types that are quite likely available anyway are `int32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.  (These are specified by C99, so most modern C++ compilers also let you use them in C++.)

Comment: `int32_t`, `uint64_t` etc are *standard* types. You can find them in the C99 standard (as `int<N>_t`, `uint<N>_t`, etc.) in the `<stdint.h>` header.

Comment: Ah, neat.  I should get a copy of the C99 standard, probably.  (Though this one was tagged C++, and technically C99 is not yet an official part of C++.  I know `int32_t` and friends are not in C++03.)

Comment: <stdint.h> is part of C++0x. Also, the new built-in types in C++0x (Unicode character types) are defined in terms of <stdint.h>.

Comment: I'm sorry for being noobish, but what are identifiers?

Comment: Oh it's the name of the variables, ahaha, yeah that would be stupid identifiers. :P

Answer (score 0):

I stay with the POSIX types defined in <stdint.h>. It seems like everyone defines their own names for things and I've had a project where the names collide. It's become a new paradigm for me to NOT define my own "pet" names for types.

Comment: You have to change your angle brackets to &gt; and &lt;
What is POSIX?

Comment: Portable Operating System Interface [for Unix] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX

Comment: So you never create classes and/or structs? :S

Comment: @Moberg: Real men use POD's for everything. It saves microseconds.