# About the paper "KD-Tree Acceleration Structures for a GPU Raytracer"

Tags: c++

I am working at raytracer picking. And read the paper "KD-Tree Acceleration Structures for a GPU Raytracer", I understand the main flow. What does 'float2', 'float3' and 'short2' in the strctures of the paper?
The paper [link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/gpu_kdtree/kdtree.pdf)

Comment: They're different data types used within the GPU / CUDA etc... see [this related question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079451/what-about-the-types-int2-int3-float2-float3-etc

Answer (score 0):

This usualy means its a multi-dimensional variable (think 2D or 3D space), thats why there is a 2 or 3 as a suffix:

`float2 variable;` means you can do: `variable.x = 0.0f; variable.y = 1.0f;`

Similar with `float3`, but this time there is also a `.z` part.

In the paper, they use these types to store a point in 2D or 3D space, thus defining bounding boxes of the KD-tree.

Comment: But at the question mentioned by 'Shane MacLaughlin', They are used in CUDA (and openCL?) where you have specific sized floats and memory usage and alignment is a big deal. float2 means 2 bytes?

Comment: float2 means actually 2 floats, so when a float is 4 bytes then a float2 would use 8 bytes.

Comment: As you said, 'leftChildPointer' of structure Spilt marked as short2, why the pointer need to use two short to represent?

Comment: I use the method for picking, but it works badly. Does it matter if there are too much equal values in the same dimension? Now the situation is: When a primitive is selected, it's correct. But most of primitives can't be selected. My kd tree's algorithm reference to [kdtree](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree#C)