# Using cuComplex with STL and C++11

Tags: c++11, cuda

My end goal here is to call cuFFT and other CUDA library functions from C++11 code. But I'm running into conflicts between `cuComplex` and other CUDA types and STL and C++ operations. For example, put the following in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   auto h_data = std::make_shared<cuComplex>(4);

   cuComplex *d_data;
   cudaMalloc((void **) &d_data, 4 * sizeof(cuComplex));
}
```

Then do `nvcc -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` to get a slew of error messages about conflicts with `float2`.

I've tried putting the code in a `.cu` file, and that switches the error messages to conflicts between `make_shared()` and `float2`. Any way to get these types & functions living happily together?

I'm running CUDA 8 on Ubuntu Xenial and compiling with clang 3.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in your usage of `make_shared`.  Based on [my read of the description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) it expects a constructible type.  There is no defined constructor for either `cuComplex` or `float2` (or `cufftComplex`), so it is unable to construct the requested object.

[None of these types are part of the c++ language standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079451/what-about-the-types-int2-int3-float2-float3-etc) (AFAIK) and so their definitions are all arising from CUDA header files.  Ultimately they are all derived from `float2` (in the CUDA header file `vector_types.h`) which defines the `struct` type but does not define a constructor for it.  Therefore the compiler has no idea how to construct an object of that type.

Presumably you are intending to use this construct in host code, so it should be safe to use `std::complex<float>` in lieu of `cuComplex` for host data storage (note the comment by @njuffa below).  It has the same data layout as `cuComplex` so it should work fine as the host side data container for host<->device data transfer.

As a proof point, we can build a constructible type around `cuComplex`, which will then compile correctly:

```
$ cat t1267.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <complex>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>

class my_fcomplex{
  cuComplex data;
  public:
  my_fcomplex(float real){
    data = make_cuFloatComplex(real, 0);}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   auto h_data = std::make_shared<std::complex<float>>(4);
   auto h2_data = std::make_shared<my_fcomplex>(4);

   cuComplex *d_data;
   cudaMalloc((void **) &d_data, 4 * sizeof(cuComplex));
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35  -std=c++11 t1267.cu -o t1267
$
```

Of course, I'm not suggesting you create your own complex types.  Just use `std::complex` for host code, as I've demonstrated above also.  Another alternative would be to use `thrust::complex`, which should mimic `std::complex` behavior in host code but is also usable in device code (and it need not be otherwise conformant to thrust code).

Comment: By design, the layout of `cuComplex` matches the layout of the complex data types defined by the ISO C, ISO C++, and ISO Fortran standards, so there is full interoperability with complex data on the host when using these languages for host code.

Comment: I'm liking the Thrust approach, at least for prototyping, to match the style on other code in the project and give a uniform complex definition. The vectors are easy enough to generate with `thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> >` and `thrust::device_vector<…>`.